# Snowflake stored procedures execution

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, qlikview, qliksense

I was trying to execute Snowflake stored procedures in Qlik Data Editor.

Snowflake stored procedures starts with CALL statement. But it will not return tabular result directly. I get a message, and we have select those results to get tabular result. I was not able to store the result message of CALL statement.

Please can anyone help how to execute a Snowflake stored procedure?

EX:

```
CALL "ODS_BI".Dimension('SK0009', 'DEBIT', 1, NULL);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use RESULT_SCAN to retrieve the results from calling a stored procedure.

As example:

```
CALL <stored_proc_name>();
```

Retrieve result set:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE(RESULT_SCAN(LAST_QUERY_ID()));
```

For more information read [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/stored-procedures-usage.html#using-result-scan-to-retrieve-the-result-from-a-stored-procedure).

Answer (score 0):

if you want to return a usable dataset then you might need to look at UDFs rather than SPs.

If you have to use a SP then this documentation explains the options available to you: [Stored Procedure Overview](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/stored-procedures-overview.html)